# Iterate through array of objects with same values in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array of objects I retrieve from JSON:

```js
[{
  "id": "19001",
  "description": "Cars",
  "first_name": "Max",
  "surname": "Madison",
  "contacts": "0743126525"
}, {
  "id": "19001",
  "description": "Cars",
  "first_name": "Elis",
  "surname": "Thunder",
  "contacts": "hello@example.com"
}]
```

I use a listview on the first page which shows me both rows. If i click and one of them it will redirect me to the next page with all details they have inside the object.

However I want combine both rows to one row with the same values and redirect me to the second page and showing me all details with the unequal values.

Example :

```
<!-- first page: -->
ID : 19001 | description Cars
```

```html
<!-- second page: -->
<p>ID: 19001<p>
<p>Description: Cars<p>
<p>first_name: Max<p>
<p>surname: Madison<p>
<p>contacts: 0743126525<p>
<p>first_name: Elis<p>
<p>surname: Thunder<p>
<p>contacts: hello@example.com<p>
```

```js
$(document).on("pageinit", "#info-page", function() {
  $.getJSON("test.json", function(info) {
    var li = "";
    var results = [];
    $.each(info, function(i, value) {
      if ($.inArray(value.description, results) === -1) {
        results.push(value.description);
        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go"> ' + value.description + '</a></li>';
      }
    });

    $("#prof-list").append(li).promise().done(function() {
      $(this).on("click", ".info-go", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#details-page").data("info", info[this.id]);
        $.mobile.changePage("#details-page");
      });
      $(this).listview("refresh");
    });
  });
});

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#details-page", function() {
  var info = $(this).data("info");
  var info_view = "";
  for (var key in info) {
    info_view = info_view + '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar field" style="font-weight : bold; text-align: left;">' + key + '</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar value" style="width : 75%">' + info[key] + '</div></div></div>';
  }

  //$('#details-page').append(info_view); 
  $(this).find("[data-role=content]").html(info_view);
});
```

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your questions properly. This was, frankly, an unreadable mess before I edited it

Comment: Also note that you're not dealing with JSON here, but an array of objects. I've edited that part of your question too

Comment: Im sorry and thanks.